# FTP download is not secure enough - password shows up in fiddler

Tags: c#, security, ftp

My application is downloading a client from my server via FTP. I *must* use FTP in this case as I made the file on my server forbidden from public use; thus, the only way to download the file is as an administrator which I can do by supplying an username and password to the FTP client. The problem with doing this, though, is that by using Fiddler I can "sniff" out the password sent to the FTP client from c#.

Code:

```
var downloadFileRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + Public.ftp_host + "//" + fileName);
            downloadFileRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Public.ftp_username, Public.ftp_password);
            downloadFileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            downloadFileRequest.UseBinary = true;

            ServicePoint sp = downloadFileRequest.ServicePoint;
            sp.ConnectionLimit = 2;

                var downloadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)downloadFileRequest.GetResponse();

                    Stream downloadStream = downloadResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Is there some way to download files via FTP without exposing this password?

Thank you,
Evan

Comment: Will the server allow you to connect via [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)?

Comment: I will have to go figure this one out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. FTP sends credentials plainly. You have to use SFTP or something equivalent.

Comment: Do you recommend any SFTP clients out there?

Comment: @Evan, We are using UltimateSFTP and it's pretty sweet, both for downloading and uploading. It does batch/folder uploads and downloads as well.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I cannot afford to pay $299 for such a service. For now I'm going to be doing the file downloads from php.

Comment: @Evan It's a bit expensive, because it's meant for enterprise development. I remember coming across http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx when I was researching options, but I didn't implement it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

No.  But can you configure an account that's only used for FTP and is not an administrator, to at least limit your exposure if someone gets the credentials?

FTP has no secure authentication mechanism.  You'd need to use something else (SFTP or SCP, or HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

If you can configure the FTP server yourself or install another one, there is a protocol called [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), which uses TLS/SSL to secure the connection over FTP.  Wikipedia has a list of [FTP server software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software) with capabilities shown.  It may be easier to HTTPS as suggested.

Any connection that is not encrypted will send the passwords in the clear.